# How to use Multiple Databases based on subdomein in Laravel

Tags: laravel, subdomain

What I want, is to access a separate database, based on the subdomain.
All other settings keep the same: username, password etc. Only database name needs to change.

I add This to database.php file

```
'subdomain' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => '',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

I also created Middleware

```
`$subdomain = $request->route()->account;

    $customer = Customer::where( 'sub_domain', $subdomain )->first();

    if( ! $customer ) {
        // account not found, do something else
    } else {
        Config::set('database.connections.subdomain.host', 'testdomain');
    }
    return $next($request);`
```

this is in route.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => $domain, 'middleware' => 'subdomain'],function () {});
```

Use `protected $connection = 'subdomain';` in Model

in .env I use default database for check customer database name

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ispsoft
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I got subdomain user database name. But not connected sudomain database And I did not get value from subdomain database

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your model's `$table`, based on the subdomain. If it's merely a different mysql schema, you should be able to do something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Widget extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    $subdomain = Config::get('database.connections.subdomain.host', 'testdomain');

    protected $table = $subdomian.'.widgets';
}
```

Comment: Can I use `$subdomain = Config::get('database.connections.subdomain.host', 'testdomain');` without function?

Comment: It looks like you're using Laravel 4.2. Is that right? If so, check out the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration. If you're using a different version, you can select your version once you're on that documentation page.

Comment: Its Laravel 5.6.*

Comment: Ok. Then I think it would be `$subdomain = config('database.connections.subdomain.host', 'testdomain');`